# What is the $\oplus$ sign mean in $R^{\oplus I}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, modules

I read a defenition of a "finite generated module":

An $R$-module $M$ is said to be *finite generated* if there exists a surjective homomorphism $R^{\oplus I}\to M$ for some finite set $I$. For $I=\{1,...,n\}$, we define $R^{\oplus I} := R^n$.

I don't understand the notation of $R^{\oplus I}$ and its meaning in this context. (For example, what happens if $I$ is finite, but does not satesfies $I=\{1,...,n\}$)? I would like to get a clearification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^{\oplus I}$ denotes the direct sum $\oplus_{i\in I} A_i$ where each $A_i=R$. 
It is a submodule of $R^I$, containing exactly those $(a_i)\in R^I$ which has only finitely many nonzero coordinates $a_i$.

Comment: It's given that $I$ is finite. Your clarification implies that in that case $R^I=R^{\oplus I}$. Am I right? If indeed $R^I=R^{\oplus I}$, what is the benefit of denoting $R^{\oplus I}$ instead of leaving the notation simple as $R^I$?

Comment: @J. Doe, clarity primarily. Also it allows arbitrary finite index sets.

Comment: When $I$ is infinite, they are different. By the way, $R^{\oplus I}$ is the *free* $R$-module on the set $I$: it is isomorphic to the set of *formal* $R$-linear combinations of elements of $I$.